# Google Maps Gradient Overlay

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have statistical information based on location in my app. I'd like to somehow display this on a google map activity. The information would best be displayed in a gradient-manner. Is there a way to easily shade portions of the map in order to create a gradient-like effect? To give you an idea of what I was thinking, imagine data based on temperature. The hotter areas are shaded red and the colder areas are shaded blue (and if possible, there is a gradient trasition between the two).

Comment: TileOverlay is the way to go using Google Maps Android API v2.